# String is fixed to screen when using libgdx

Tags: java, string, text, camera, libgdx

I've been having some trouble with libgdx and my code and I wanted to know how you can make the text stop moving with the camera. What I wanted to do was label the corridnates of a 2d array that I created but when I do the text moves with the camera.

here's what I wrote:

```
    batch.begin();
    for(int x = 0; x < world.getWidth(); x+=size){
        for(int y = 0; y < world.getHeight(); y +=size){
            Room r = (Room)dCreator.getRooms(x/size,y/size);
            font.draw(batch, x+", "+y, r.getX(), r.getY());
        }
    }
    batch.end();
```

Any help or questions would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new camera, which won't move like the other. It is very common to have more cameras in a game, mostly one for rendering game and the second one for GUI.

```
OrthographicCamera gameCam = new OrthographicCamera();
OrthographicCamera guiCam = new OrthographicCamera();
guiCam.setToOrtho(false, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
gameCam.setToOrtho(false, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
```

and then in code:

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);
batch.begin();
//render game stuff
batch.end();

batch.setProjectionMatrix(guiCam.combined);
batch.begin();
//draw gui, text, etc..
batch.end();
```

And remember only to move the gameCam, not the guiCam.